# How to use Ctrl-P to interactively search file contents for all files in a project?

Tags: search, plugin-ctrlp

I tried today to perform a search on every files of a project.
I use [Ctrl-P](https://github.com/kien/ctrlp.vim) and search on lines like so :

[image: screenshot]

But the result of the search is only on the previously opened file. Here I open only `main.php`.

Do you know a way to search on all files without having to open them one by one ?

Comment: This is something I want as well. If you're using ack or ag, performance shouldn't be an issue. Plus if you're using neovim, it should be async, so there shouldn't be any block either.

Comment: Finally I use ag as ctrlp command :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`:CtrlPLine` is actually supposed to work on listed buffers.

If you *absolutely* want to use that feature on every file in your project, you could add them to the argument list (and thus the buffer list) with something like:

```
:argadd **/*.php
```

but that doesn't sound like a very good idea for performance reasons.

Using `:vimgrep` or `:grep` sounds a lot better to me:

```
:vim foo **/*.php
:cw
```

You lose the "fuzziness" of CtrlP, obviously, but you get reliability and flexibility in return.

Reference:

```
:help :argadd
:help :vimgrep
:help :grep
:help :cwindow
:help quickfix
```

Comment: A key difference between CtrlP and vim-grep, is CtrlP is *interactive*.

Answer (score 1):

You should use thoses plugins [Sidesearch](https://github.com/ddrscott/vim-side-search) or [fzf](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf.vim)

Both allow to search in recursive directories using silversearch-ag

fzf allow to search on the listed files which include your string.

Comment: Hi @MisterBanal, welcome on our site! You should precise in your answer if these plugins can be interfaced with CtrlP as OP asked. If they can be interfaced you should explain how and if they can't you should at least give a basic example of how to use them otherwise your answer doesn't really answer the question. (You can change your answer with the "edit" button under the text).